# Installing the 'responds_to_parent' plugin on Mac OS running "Snow Leopard"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, terminal, installation

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://khamsouk.souvanlasy.com/articles/ajax-file-uploads-in-rails-using-attachment_fu-and-responds_to_parent) to AJAXfy file uploads in my Ruby on Rails 3 application. On "Step 6. Using iframes and responds_to_parent" chapter I have to install the 'responds_to_parent' plugin but I am not able.

I use a Mac OS running "Snow Leopard", so in my Terminal I enter this:

```
script/plugin install http://responds-to-parent.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

but the response is:

```
-bash: script/plugin: No such file or directory
```

What I have to enter?

---

BTW: "what I have to do"/"how to handle" gem and plugins for the my RoR 3 application when I will deploy it on a hosting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script/plugin install` is no longer in rails. Use this syntax instead:

```
rails plugin install
```

All the executables inside the script directory were consolidated into `script/rails` with the release of Rails 3.

As far as deploying goes, using `rails plugin install` will add the code to your /vendor/plugins directory, so as long as you check that into your source control system, it should deploy with the rest of your code.  Gems should be included in the Gemfile.  You will need to use "bundle install --deployment".  If you are using capistrano, there is a recipe included with bundler.  More info on bundler here: http://gembundler.com/

Comment: clone it into your vendor/plugins directory.  If you have the git client installed, go to your shell and "cd /your_rails_app/vendor/plugins"  and "git clone  git://github.com/itkin/respond_to_parent.git".  This will install it as a plugin